# divs are overlapped I'm trying to use margin-top:100px; but I feel it's not the best way

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-position

I have 2 divs that overlapped, the text on the top is  position: absolute; as there's z-index and after adding the second div they overlapped !!

[1] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUDSm.jpg "The 2 DIVs"

```css
.content .box{
 width: 400px;
 height:400px;
 border-radius: 10%;
 transform: rotate(-15deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-15deg);
 background-color: white;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-top: -80px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 z-index: -2;
}
.content h1 {
 transform: rotate(15deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(15deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(15deg);
 font-family: 'Nexa light';
 font-size: 25px;
 margin-left: 60px;
 margin-top: 70px;
}
.content h1:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #f2d44b;
 width: 280px;
 margin-top: -15px;

}
.content > p {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 75px;
 text-align: justify;
 line-height: 35px;
 font-family: 'Nexa light';
 font-size: 1em ;
 padding-right: 75px;
 border:2px solid red;

}
.milestone {
 margin-top: 250px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 485px;
 background: linear-gradient(rgba(42,39, 61, 0.5), rgba(42, 39, 61, 0.5)),url('_2/BG.jpg') ;
 background-position: center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover; float: left;

}
.milestone .left{
 float: left;
 width: 2px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
 margin-left: 100px;
 position: absolute;
}
.milestone .left img {
 position: relative;
 top: 12%;
 left: -20px;
 width: 39px;
 height: 40px;
}
.milestone .right ul {
 float: left;
 display: table;
 float: left;
 color: white;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-top: 10%;
}
.milestone .right ul li {
 list-style: none;
}
.milestone .right ul li:nth-child(1) {
 font-family: 'Nexa bold';
 font-size: 35px;
}
.milestone .right ul li:nth-child(2) {
 color: #f2d44b;
 font-family: 'Nexa light';
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: left;
}
.milestone .right ul li:nth-child(3) {
 font-family: 'Nexa light';
 font-size: 15px;
 width: 550px;
 line-height: 30px;
 float: left;
 text-align: justify;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class='content'>
  <div class='box'><h1>What’s Kidney Rejection</h1></div>
  <p>
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


  </p>
</div>


<div class='milestone '>
 <div class="right">
  <ul>
  <li col-sm-4><h3>Milestone 1 progress 1/6/2017 to 31/10/2017</h3></li>
  <li ><p>Milestone name of title</p></li>
  <li class='col-md-12 col-sm-4'><p>The project has started in June 2017, and is expected to be completed in two years. The project deliverables include the fully-functioning system prototype with the recommended hardware setup and user’s manual, as well as the full software stack and APIs.</p></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="left">
  <img src="number.png">
 </div>

</div> 


</div>
```

I have 2 divs that overlapped,
the text on the top is  `position: absolute;` as there's `z-index`
and after adding the second div they overlapped !!

[1] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUDSm.jpg "The 2 DIVs"

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?

Comment: @AravindS sure, just a minute

Comment: I added it as a answer @AravindS

Comment: Please dont do that..update in you question itself...see here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: and also tell how you want to show the content

Comment: @AravindS here we are :D I added the code here

Comment: your image links are not opening.

Comment: @AravindS 
the Images are not important, I just want the milestone section be separated from the rest thanks a lot, this box is a shape so I need my text to be over it like that :imgur.com/a/hdNlKu1 so I made z-index with absolute position . but my second div (Milestone) overlapped. ** I need my content box and p overlapped but didn't need milestone and p overlapped

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the HTML structure you are intending. But I can see there are many CSS style issues. I have tried cleared those styles which seems irrelevant to me and now all elements have started taking the relevant space. Please tell your requirement what you are trying to achieve.

```css
  .content .box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.content h1 {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(15deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(15deg);
  font-family: 'Nexa light';
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.content h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #f2d44b;
  width: 280px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.content>p {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-family: 'Nexa light';
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-right: 75px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.milestone {
  margin-top: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 485px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(42, 39, 61, 0.5), rgba(42, 39, 61, 0.5)), url('_2/BG.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.milestone .left {
  float: left;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.milestone .left img {
  width: 39px;
  height: 40px;
}

.milestone .right ul {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.milestone .right ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.milestone .right ul li:nth-child(1) {
  font-family: 'Nexa bold';
  font-size: 35px;
}

.milestone .right ul li:nth-child(2) {
  color: #f2d44b;
  font-family: 'Nexa light';
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

.milestone .right ul li:nth-child(3) {
  font-family: 'Nexa light';
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 550px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='box'>
      <h1>What’s Kidney Rejection</h1>
    </div>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
      printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
      has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
      remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem
      Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
      printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


    </p>
  </div>


  <div class='milestone '>
    <div class="right">
      <ul>
        <li col-sm-4>
          <h3>Milestone 1 progress 1/6/2017 to 31/10/2017</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Milestone name of title</p>
        </li>
        <li class='col-md-12 col-sm-4'>
          <p>The project has started in June 2017, and is expected to be completed in two years. The project deliverables include the fully-functioning system prototype with the recommended hardware setup and user’s manual, as well as the full software stack
            and APIs.</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
      <img src="number.png">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, 
this box is a shape so I need my text to be over it like that :https://imgur.com/a/hdNlKu1
so I made z-index with absolute position . but my second div (Milestone) overlapped.
** I need my content box and p overlapped but didn't need milestone and p overlapped

Comment: I have added another answer where in I have updated your code to remove the specific style which was making your code to overlap. Please check

Comment: @EsraaAli , Can you please make this question as accepted if your problem is solved?

Answer (score 0):

Your divs are not overlapping as of now. Please check below snippet.

```css
.content .box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: -80px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}

.content h1 {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(15deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(15deg);
  font-family: 'Nexa light';
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.content h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #f2d44b;
  width: 280px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.content>p {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-family: 'Nexa light';
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-right: 75px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.milestone {
  margin-top: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 485px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(42, 39, 61, 0.5), rgba(42, 39, 61, 0.5)), url('_2/BG.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
}

.milestone .left {
  float: left;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.milestone .left img {
  position: relative;
  top: 12%;
  left: -20px;
  width: 39px;
  height: 40px;
}

.milestone .right ul {
  float: left;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.milestone .right ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.milestone .right ul li:nth-child(1) {
  font-family: 'Nexa bold';
  font-size: 35px;
}

.milestone .right ul li:nth-child(2) {
  color: #f2d44b;
  font-family: 'Nexa light';
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

.milestone .right ul li:nth-child(3) {
  font-family: 'Nexa light';
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 550px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='box'>
      <h1>What’s Kidney Rejection</h1>
    </div>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
      printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
      has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
      remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem
      Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
      printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


    </p>
  </div>


  <div class='milestone '>
    <div class="right">
      <ul>
        <li col-sm-4>
          <h3>Milestone 1 progress 1/6/2017 to 31/10/2017</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Milestone name of title</p>
        </li>
        <li class='col-md-12 col-sm-4'>
          <p>The project has started in June 2017, and is expected to be completed in two years. The project deliverables include the fully-functioning system prototype with the recommended hardware setup and user’s manual, as well as the full software stack
            and APIs.</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
      <img src="number.png">
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```